# React API response Data, display on another page

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new to `Reactjs` and want some help. I have `formik form`, when I click on `SUBMIT` it calls `back end API`. After successful `API` returns some `JSON` Response.

How can I display that `JSON` response in table format on another page (new page).

```
<Formik
      initialValues={initialValues1}
      validationSchema={validation}
      onSubmit={values => {
        console.log("onSubmit", JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          //Send Data to BackendAPI, after successful response display in another page
      }}
    >

 ......

 <Form noValidate autoComplete="off">

  .......

  <Button type="submit">SUBMIT</Button>

 </Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you got a response in data object. so you can set that data into state like below:

> this.setState({items: data});

Then you can pass that state into another component. Complete examples is given here:

**Parent Component** which will be in App.js

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {PChild} from "./PChild";

export class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let data = [];
        data.push({track: { id:1, name: 'Black Sabbath, from the album Black Sabbath (1970)'}});
        data.push({track: { id:2, name: 'Blackfield, from the album Blackfield (2004)'}});
        data.push({track: { id:3, name: 'Bo Diddley, from the album Bo Diddley (1958)'}});
        data.push({track: { id:4, name: 'Damn Yankees, from the album Damn Yankees (1990)'}});
        this.setState({items: data});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <PChild items={this.state.items} name="Khabir"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child Component** which is used in Parent Component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

// Parent to Child communication
export class PChild extends React.Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(this.props.items);
        console.log(this.props.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.items.map((item, i) => {
                    return <li key={item.track.id}>
                        {(`Item ${i+1} - ${item.track.name}`)}
                    </li>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Update:**: As per your comment, I added the following code.

```
const Example = (props) => {
    const [credential, setCredential] = useState({});
    const [response, setResponse] = useState({});

    const callUpdateApi = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: credential.email,
                    password: credential.password,
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            })
                .then(response => setResponse(response.json()))
                .then(json => console.log(json));
            console.warn(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues1}
                validationSchema={validation}
                onSubmit={values => {
                    console.log("onSubmit", JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    //Send Data to BackendAPI, after successful response display in another page
                    setCredential(values);
                    callUpdateApi();

                }}
            >
                {response ? <PChild items={response}/> : null}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I have updated my question with some code snippet. Can you please let me how can I send to child page in this case.

Comment: Hi @ppb, I have added another example in my answer. Please check it. In new example, I set values in credential using useState and the called api. after getting response from api, response data is passed to child component.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Hi @Khabir could you please help me with the same solution, but in functional component: I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430794/how-can-i-display-the-response-in-a-new-page